# how to reset the step counter flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to calculate the steps using flutter 
and found this plugin
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pedometer

but can't reset the counter to 0 even when i close the app it still the old counter

I tried to recall the initPlatformState() method again but didn't work

> if you have another way or plugin please share it

**update** it resets only if i restart the device.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';//
import 'dart:async';//

import 'package:flutter_pedometer/flutter_pedometer.dart';//package name

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _stepCountValue = 'Unknown';
  StreamSubscription<int> _subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    FlutterPedometer pedometer = new FlutterPedometer();
    _subscription = pedometer.stepCountStream.listen(_onData,
        onError: _onError, onDone: _onDone, cancelOnError: true);

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;
  }

  void _onData(int stepCountValue) async {
    print(stepCountValue);

    setState(() {
      _stepCountValue = "$stepCountValue";
    });
  }

  void _onDone() {}

  void _onError(error) {
    print("Flutter Pedometer Error: $error");
  }
//
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Text('Steps taken: $_stepCountValue\n'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to unsubscribe from your stream?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the implementation of pedometer, and the project is 404, but If you promise the plugin works, you could just record `_stepCountValue` in [sharedPreference](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) while changing, and when you init a value, you could just use `_stepCountValue -  preservedValue` to get a init zero value.

Comment: @Amsakanna if you mean _subscription.cancel() i did it not working

Comment: @Tokenyet nice idea but aren't there anyway to do it from same plugin ?

Comment: @suhaibsalem you can't reset the step count value using something inside the plugin it self

Answer (score -1):

You can `stopListening` with `_subscription.cancel();`